# Override a single method from a generic controller

Tags: c#, generics, overriding

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseController<T,K> : ApiController
{
  //several methods

  [Route("{id:int}")]
  public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody]T item)
  {
    //updates the item
  }
}
```

I have 6 other classes (Controllers) that inherits the BaseController and uses the methods there declared. I need to override the `put` method on the UserController, and only on the UserController.
I´ve tried:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T,K> : ApiController
{
  //several methods

  [Route("{id:int}")]
  public virtual HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody]T item)
  {
    //updates the item
  }
}

public class UserController : BaseController<User, UserDT>
{
  [Route("{id:int}")]
  public override HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody]User item)
  {
    //updates the user
  } 
}
```

but it throws the error: `Multiple actions were found that match the request`

How can I override the method?

---EDIT----
This is my WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

---EDIT---
added the `[Route("{id:int}")]`

Comment: Are you sure your routes are correct? I suspect the controller is not correctly specified by your route.

Comment: Updated the question with routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Route attribute off of the override.  That is producing 2 identical routes based on the id:int route and the data type of the body.  The override will still be executed in place of the base method due to polymorphism.